# How to update an extension while pending review in Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an extension pending review in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions). I discovered it has a significant bug.

The Developer Dashboard does not allow uploading an updated package while another is pending review.

How can I withdraw the package pending review so I can upload an updated one with the bug fixed?

Comment: There's no way AFAIK. The entire web store is a joke so don't be surprised.

Comment: We'd think after over a decade these types of issues would be ironed out by Google...

Comment: Well, so I'd submitted my extension for review, but later I figured there's a bug. I have to wait for them to review the extension with bug to be able to submit bug-free extension. It still is a joke...

Comment: I just spent a day rewriting lots of code after I discovered that my extension had gone on the 'slow review queue'. So, now I have to wait for v1.0 to get through the slow queue, before they can review v1.1 on the fast queue.